# CLIENT APP ERROR - Neither the view or container of the UITargetedPreview is currently in a window (UIKit without table views or collection views)

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uikit

I have an iPad application that has some UIButtons in a view on the left, and I would like to drag a button to the right with a different but simple view as the drag preview. There are no table views or collection views involved here, everything is a UIView or descendant.

Everything is working fine, but I get this error in the console as soon as the button hold is complete and the drag starts:

`2022-09-30 09:58:37.378254-0400 MyApp[9837:259879] [Assert] CLIENT APP ERROR - Neither the view or container of the UITargetedPreview is currently in a window. This is in violation of UIDragInteraction API contract and can cause a severe visual glich. THIS IS A CLIENT APP BUG and will soon be a hard assert. PLEASE FIX ME`

Here is my pertinent code that handles the drag and drop and creating the preview view for the drag operation:

```
@IBOutlet var leftView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var rightView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var leftButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // do something here

    let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
    leftButton.addInteraction(dragInteraction)
    leftButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
    rightView.addInteraction(dropInteraction)
}

func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, prefersFullSizePreviewsFor session: UIDragSession) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let test = UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
    test.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "highlight_color")

    let viewContainer = ViewContainer(view: test)
    let provider = NSItemProvider(object: viewContainer)
    let item = UIDragItem(itemProvider: provider)
    item.localObject = viewContainer.view

    // keep reading the question for more information on this
    item.previewProvider = {
        return UIDragPreview(view: viewContainer.view)
    }

    return [item]
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.items.count == 1
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
    return UIDropProposal(operation: .move)
}

func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    var dropLocation = session.location(in: pdfView)
    print("dropInteraction performDrop dropLocation: \(dropLocation)")
    
    // do something here
}
```

Running the code as is shown above, everything is working fine, I get the preview I want and the drop location comes out correctly, the only problem is the warning in the console.

If I comment out the `item.previewProvider` block in the itemsForBeginning method above, I no longer get the warning in the console, but then I am dragging around a ghosted image of the button instead of the preview view that I created.

All of the narratives that I could find regarding iOS drag and drop talked about table views and collection views, so they did not appear to directly help with my issue.

Anyone have any ideas of what I could try? Thanks.

BTW Apple, not to nit pick, but you misspelled "glitch" in the warning. Perhaps I should file a radar?